# How to make a div follow the cursor, but shifted by Xpx towards the center of window?

Tags: javascript, trigonometry

Div should follow the cursor, but shifted 20px by X and Y axis toward the center of the screen, based on the quarter in which is the mouse cursor?

Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDXZV.png

I used trigonometry to find vector from cursor to center of the window, so I have cursor coordinates, center coordinates, and third point C, but div moves in strange circles and I don't where I made mistake.

```
var lt = document.getElementById('lt')
var ltPosition = lt.getBoundingClientRect();
var element = document.getElementById('element');
var mousePosX = 0; 
var mousePosY = 0; 

document.onmousemove = function(e){
    function angle(xCursor, yCursor, xCenter, yCenter){
        var distanceA = xCursor - xCenter;
        var distanceB = yCursor - yCenter;
        var distanceC = Math.sqrt(distanceA*distanceA + distanceB*distanceB);

        var theta = Math.atan2(distanceA, distanceB);
        theta *= 180 / Math.PI;

        var offsetX = distanceC * Math.sin(theta);
        var offsetY = distanceC * Math.cos(theta);

        function follow(x,y){
            element.style.left =  x + "px";
            element.style.top = y +"px";
        }
        follow(e.clientX + offsetX, e.clientY + offsetY);   
    }
    angle(e.clientX, e.clientY, ltPosition.right, ltPosition.bottom);
}
```

Here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sgvpvqhc/

What else should I do here in order to have this functionality?

Comment: without reading too deep into the code, you might've mixed sin and cos, sin is typically offset in Y, cos is offset in X.

Comment: @VladimirM true, but he also mixed the arguments to `atan2`, so it doesn't matter in the result.

Comment: You'll probably love Canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is that `theta *= 180 / Math.PI;` doing there? `sin` and `cos` take the angle in radians, just like `atan` returns it. If you want to display it, sure, convert it to degrees, but inside the `Math` API no conversion are needed.

([updated fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sgvpvqhc/2/))

Comment: I guess I just need to normalize vector length now?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Also the vector currently points outwards, not to the center, so also negate it. And maybe don't use a fixed offset but something that becomes `0` when you come near the center so that the icon doesn't jump.

Comment: For example, [this](https://jsfiddle.net/sgvpvqhc/3/) looks pretty nice

Comment: Can you give me formula for vector normalization?

Comment: @11223342124 You just need to use a constant `distanceC` and you're done. But there are also [formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector#Cartesian_coordinates) that don't need trigonometric functions.

Comment: Hey @Bergi , can you please explain me what this line does `distanceC = -Math.min(distanceC/2, 20);` ? If you can remember..

Comment: The vector you are using points from the centre outwards. To shift your `div` by 20px towards the centre, you need to use `distanceC = -20` when calculating the offset (a vector of length 20 towards the centre). But that looks weird when the cursor is near the centre, and it even jumps when passing it, so I thought I'd smoothen it [like this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y+%3D+-min(x%2F2,+20)+from+x%3D0+to+100).

Answer (score 0):

I though you might like this. I put it here too. https://jsfiddle.net/sgvpvqhc/5/

```js
function mouseMover(element, offX, offY) {
  var e = element,
    bc = e.getBoundingClientRect();
  var ox = offX,
    oy = offY;
  if (ox === undefined && oy === undefined) {
    ox = -Math.round(bc.width / 2);
    oy = -Math.round(bc.height / 2);
  }
  e.parentNode.onmousemove = function(eventObj) {
    var ev = eventObj,
      b = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    var x = Math.round(ev.clientX - b.left);
    var y = Math.round(ev.clientY - b.top);
    e.style.left = x + (ox) + 'px';
    e.style.top = y + (oy) + 'px';
  }
}
mouseMover(document.getElementById('element'), 20, 20)
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#lt, #rt, #ld, #rd {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#element {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#lt, #rd {
  background-color: green;
}

#rt, #ld {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id='container' class='container'>
  <div id='element'></div>
  <div id='lt'></div>
  <div id='rt'></div>
  <div id='ld'></div>
  <div id='rd'></div>
</div>
<div class='box'></div>
```

Comment: What's the `Math.round` good for? And what happened to the shift?

Comment: `EventObject.clientX` and `EventObject.clientY` return decimal numbers in some Browsers. Also, the `element` that is moving may be an odd size. shift? If you mean the scroll bar issue that is because OP wants to use percentages, which is okay, but only in a fixed size element. My example does not cover that. Sorry, but  he can fix it himself.

Comment: Yes, but CSS also allows decimal numbers for its properties, so that shouldn't be a problem. Regarding the offset, the OP asked for "*shifted 20px by X and Y axis toward the center of the screen*".

Comment: My mouseMover function takes 2 arguments after the `element` argument,  which can also be negative if need be. Without the args it just centers the `element`. Note that `offX` and `offY` are based on the upper left corner of `element`.